# What is the best way to structure a big Front-End project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, design-patterns, frontend

I'm currently creating a big multi-page project using Node.js and EJS as template engine and I'm having some problems organizing my code. I've only only found recommendations **regarding css and js patterns**, but little information about **Front-End Architecture**. So far this is the [best link](https://www.sitepoint.com/good-front-end-architecture/) I've found about this topic.

I'm about to re-order my code as follows:

```
\views
      home.ejs
      about.ejs
    products.ejs
         \partials
            header.ejs
            footer.ejs

\css
    \home
        home.css
    \about
        about.css
    \products
        produtcs.css
 \imgs
 \js
      \controllers
          home.js
          about.js
       products.js
      \libs
          jquery.js
          analytics.js
      \plugins
          jquery.tooltip.js
          textResize.js
          formValidation.js
```

Recommendations are more than welcome.

Comment: As long as you have an organizational system that is easy to remember for your team, regardless of how many files populate the folders, you're good. Personally, I often put my \css \img and \js all in a \res folder because I find that the most time is spent on the \views folder, but again, that's just me.

Comment: You are right, I spend most of the time in the view folder. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Don't put your controllers into js path, Controllers must be on the same side/degree from views.

Answer (score 2):

from your current structure i can figure out that you structure your folders by type (e.g. controllers). For huge app it may start to be diffucult maintain such structure and i think that structuring by feature (e.g. home, about, products) could save your time in future.

A good article can be found here (it's for angular.js, but patterns are always similar):
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure